# How to keep backslash in the result of a regular expression, when working in Python?

Tags: python, regex, escaping

The strings I want to match includes some escape sequences, like 'It\'s something'. It's no problem to match it with '.*?', however the result is escaped automatically. How to prevent the automatic escaping, and keep the backslashes as they are?

For example:

```
>>> re.findall('\((?P<content>.*?)\)','(It\'s something)')
["It's something"]
```

And what I want is:

```
[r"It\'s something"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no backslash in your input string.

```
>>> re.findall('\((?P<content>.*?)\)', r'(It\'s something)')
["It\\'s something"]
>>> ["It\\'s something"] == [r"It\'s something"]
True
```

Comment: Thanks! In this case, make the input string raw is essential :)

Answer (score 3):

The input string needs to be a raw string also.  Otherwise, it is converted before the regex sees it:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\((?P<content>.*?)\)',r'(It\'s something)')
["It\\'s something"]
>>> _ == [r"It\'s something"]
True
```